# big query command line to execute multiple sql files

Tags: google-bigquery

Does anyone here knows how to execute multiple sql files in bq command line? Sample if I have 2 sql files named test1.sql and test2.sql, how should I do it?

If I do this:

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false > test1.sql

this only executes the test1.sql.

What I want to do is to execute both test1.sql and tes2.sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't : [bq query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference?hl=fr#bq_query)

Best option if you want one line is to use the `&&` operator.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false > test1.sql && bq query --use_legacy_sql=false > test2.sql
```

Comment: Do we have any option where we can loop thru several sql files? This is just an example but in reality I have like between 10-15 sql files and it would be tedious to do if I'd join all of it thru &&. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way, which is using a shell script in order to loop through all of the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="/path/to/sqls"
for f in $FILES
do
  bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < "$f"
done
```